# Can't init static calendar in initialize method of NSDate category

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nscalendar

I've created a helpers category for NSDate (NSDate+Helpers). Here is a caching for the calendar object I'm going to use inside the category implementation:

```
static NSCalendar* currentCalendar = nil;
@implementation NSDate (Helpers)

+(void)initialize{
    currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
}
@end
```

The problem is that my application doesn't starts anymore. I see only black screen. I would like to know what I am doing wrong. You can get same problem on clean test project.

Comment: So what have you done to debug it?

Comment: @HotLicks just went through commits and found that this was a problem

Comment: (Understand that you've probably broken NSDate's own `initialize` method.)

Comment: @HotLicks so there is no way to implement calendar caching in NSDate categories with 2 lines of code?

Comment: Does it work if you delete the entire `+initialize` method?

Comment: @PartiallyFinite yes it does

Comment: I didn't say that.  But defining an `initialize` method in a category is probably dangerous.  There are plenty of ways to implement caching without using `initialize`.  (Though it might take 4-5 lines of code.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a category to override an existing method, you overwrite the original implementation, so `NSDate`'s original `+initialize` method never gets executed. In this case, it looks like it's doing something in that method that's necessary for its own internal functionality, and this is breaking your app.

Even if this is not the issue, overriding the `+initialize` method is a bad idea, and doing any custom object instantiation there is an especially bad idea.

Try initialising the calendar object somewhere else, e.g. in `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` in your app's delegate.

Another thing you can do is implement the calendar as a singleton in your category, like so:

```
@implementation NSDate (Helpers)

- (NSCalendar *)myCurrentCalendar {
    static NSCalendar *currentCalendar; // static property
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;   // token for dispatch
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar]; // initialise
    });
    return currentCalendar; // return the calendar
}
```

Then, when you need to use it, you access it as `[NSDate myCurrentCalendar]`. This will initialise the calendar **the first time you call this method**, and on subsequent calls to the method will simply immediately return the calendar.

Comment: `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions`? really? so bad :(

Comment: @purrrminator see the updated answer for another option